# Does wordpress add their own classes into nav menus?

Tags: theme-development, menus, html

I am building a theme and have noticed that when I create a menu with just html or have it dynamically add menu items based on pages it looks how it was meant to be. Although when I change the code to generate the menu from the menu editor it adds alot of extra padding to the menu.

Is this a wordpress issue? Has anyone heard of this before? Here is an example.

When I generate a menu using the menu editor it adds padding:

```
 <div class="header">
    <div class="nav">

<ul>

       <li>

       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

       </li>


</ul>
```

When I generate a menu through just hardcoding HTML it looks fine:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Problem has been solved. I removed both the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags and the navigation is in it's proper location.

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="nav">

           <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: `wp_nav_menu` generates a full unordered list - having it within `<li>` tags like your first block of code would mean the generated menu is a list-within-a-list, which may explain the padding...

Comment: Are you referring to extra *whitespace* in the markup or *padding* in terms of CSS and alignment?

Comment: Referring to padding in terms of CSS. It is using the same classes when I check but for some reason the links are moved down quite a bit.

Comment: @AndyAdams I tried removing the <li> and I am having the same issue. I have my own li and ul classes that I use. When I check to see what it is using it is inheriting extra classes from a user agent stylesheet for those. So it appears that it is ignoring my classes. I don't know how to switch it back though.

Comment: Oops. I didn't see that it added extra <UL> tags aswell. After removing those it seems to work.

Comment: @user1632018 glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

@user1632018 reports that the problem has been solved:

> I removed both the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags and now the navigation is in its
>   proper location:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```